# Return php obj to javascript callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I get the `print_r()` output in the `done()` so I can check on `data.email` and  `data.url`

### jQuery

```
    $.post("php/checkinput.php", {
        email: contactEmail.val(),
        url: contactWebsite.val()
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data)
        doCheck(data)
    });
```

### PHP

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$url = $_POST["url"];
$obj = new stdClass();
$arr = array();
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $obj->email = "invalid";
} else {
    $obj->email = "valid";
}
//array_push($obj, $arr)
if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    $obj->url = "invalid";
} else {
    $obj->url = "valid";
}
print_r($obj);
//Object
//(
    //[email] => invalid
    //[url] => invalid
//)
```

Comment: try to convert $obj to string or i'll suggest JSON string and then echo it. You can easily parse JSON string by JSON.parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to return a valid javascript object, so, you should use a JSON String...

```
echo json_encode($obj);
exit;
```

and, in your javascript:

```
$.post().then(function(data) { console.log(data); });
```

I think that data is already decoded, but, if it isn't, you can do:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$arr = [email=>$obj->email,url=>$obj->url];
echo json_encode($arr);
exit;

 $.post("php/checkinput.php", {
        email: contactEmail.val(),
        url: contactWebsite.val()
    },success(function(data){
        console.log(data.email,data.url);
        doCheck(data)
    });
```